# How to Add a class to dynamically Created Row in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jgGrid, I am adding a row dynamically to jq Grid like

```
 function addRow() {

    rowids++;

    var myfirstrow = { ID: rowids, PartyCode: "", PartyName: "g", ContainerType: "", TransactionType: "", GoodQuantity: "", Remark: "" };

    jQuery("#ContainerVehicalRecoveryGrid").addRowData(rowids, myfirstrow);


},
```

Now, I want to Add a class "PartyCode" to Column PartyCode, How to add that, i have tried different types, but not getting, please help me anyone.

Comment: try to use `cellattr` in `jqGrid` : 

    `cellattr: function(rowId, rawObject) {
            return " class='PartyCode'";
    }`

Comment: Why you not just use `classes: "PartyCode"` property in the column `PartyCode`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('#ContainerVehicalRecoveryGrid tbody tr:last td').eq(1).addClass("yourClass");
```

this is work for me.

Comment: But please note add record to last of grid like jQuery("#ContainerVehicalRecoveryGrid").addRowData(rowids, myfirstrow,"last");